# Uploading pdf files to Sharepoint via Python (cross-tenant/domain)

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a script that creates PDFs using a Python Script. I intend to have the script push the PDFs to a folder in Sharepoint. I am considering one of the following approaches -

1. Using the Microsoft Graph API
2. By Network Mapping

With Option 1, my credentials are on a tenant that's different from the Sharepoint destination. I am not sure if Files.ReadWrite permission will work with a cross-tenant mail. What permissions would need to be setup if I go with Option 1?

With Option 2, I am wondering if I can map the SharePoint as a drive in my local machine. But the issue here is that I am not set up in Sharepoint as a user. I login from another domain using my email and a code assigned to me. Would a user account need to be setup in the Sharepoint destination to be able to do this?

Thanks!

I have been trying to upload PDF files to a Sharepoint destination. I am trying to access a Sharepoint drive which is on another tenant/domain.